# inline two elements using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

Im practicing my bootstrap skills but somehow I got stuck in inlining the input and select

this is the output that I want

[image]

However I got this somehow

[image]

by using this code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>Length of Stay</label>
  <div class="form-group d-inline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <select class="custom-select">
      <option disabled selected>Select Length</option>
      <option value="Years">Years</option>
      <option value="Months">Months</option>
      <option value="Days">Days</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

any idea how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added bootstrap class `d-flex`  to `form-group`. thanks

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>Length of Stay</label>
  <div class="form-group d-flex">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <select class="custom-select">
      <option disabled selected>Select Length</option>
      <option value="Years">Years</option>
      <option value="Months">Months</option>
      <option value="Days">Days</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `display:flex;` to do this. That way it is much easier for you to align your elements. Try this test code

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>Length of Stay</label>
  <div class="form-group d-flex flex-row">
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div>
      <select class="custom-select">
                   <option disabled selected>Select Length</option>
                   <option value="Years">Years</option>
                   <option value="Months">Months</option>
                   <option value="Days">Days</option>
               </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/ucsvpb29/